# JQuery autonumeric set does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code to calculate the total price based on the quantity and unit price. So I define a text box and initially format it using the following:

```
$('.Num').autoNumeric({ aSep: ',', vMin: '0.00', vMax: '9999999999999999.99', wEmpty: 'zero' });
```

So my amount textbox will display the amount with the thousand separator. Then if I edit the quantity, I want to recalculate the amount. The code is as following:

```
var amount = parseFloat($('#' + idQty)[0].value.replace(/\,/g, '') * $('#' + idPrice)[0].innerHTML.replace(/\,/g, ''));
amount = RoundNumber(amount, 2);
$('#' + idAmt).autoNumeric('init', { aSep: ',', vMin: '0.00', vMax: '9999999999999999.99', wEmpty: 'zero' });
$('#' + idAmt).autoNumeric('set', parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2));
```

But the value is not set to `amount`. What am I doing wrong here?

[EDIT]: I am using autoNumeric plugin, which can be found [here](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/).

Comment: Are you using a plugin..? if so it'll be helpful to tag it or mention in in question...

Comment: It looks like amount is already a number. Why do you call parseFloat on it?

Comment: Actually it is mentioned in the topic, anyway I am adding the link to the plugin as well.

Comment: @AustinMullins `parseFloat` is required as the amount maybe an integer here. The `RoundNumber` function is a custom function that may return integer if the result is integer (e.g. 1*2 = 2). Anyway the main issue here is the textbox not being set to `amount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up solving this issue by replacing the last three lines above with the below:

```
amount = parseFloat(RoundNumber(amount, 2)).toFixed(2);
$('#' + idAmt).val(numberWithCommas(amount));
```

As for `numberWithCommas` is to format the number with comma separator

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```